# CSS Borders not aligned with content

Tags: css

Good day!

I recently added borders to my dropdown menu, sadly the hover color is not aligning with the border, so there is a small line left.

[image: Code for CSS and HTML]

Strange thing is if you hover over the line, the parent will be selected but the object itself is not and you can not click it either.

I want to make the hover align with the border, so there is no dark stripe infront of the cell.

You can see it here: https://jsbin.com/cejigelobi/edit?html,css,output
Click on the 3 stripes -> Click on Products -> Hover over a submenu and you will see.

HTML:

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #001728;
  --darker-background-color: #000000;
  --accent-color: #20cc5b;
  --text-color: #FFFFFF;
  --navbar-height: 80px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: var(--background-color);
}

nav {
  height: var(--navbar-height);
  background-color: var(--background-color);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom: 4px solid var(--accent-color);
}

nav .logo {
  margin-left: 30px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  height: 100%;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: var(--accent-color);
}

nav ul a {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  height: min-content;
  width: 200px;
  background: var(--background-color);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-left: 2px solid var(--accent-color);
  border-right: 2px solid var(--accent-color);
  border-bottom: 4px solid var(--accent-color);
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: var(--navbar-height);
}

.dropdown li {
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown li a {
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding-left: 30px;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
}

nav li:hover .dropdown {
  display: flex;
}

nav input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.expandable_li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.toggle_button {
  width: 30px;
  height: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 25px;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.bar {
  height: 4px;
  width: 100%;
  background: var(--text-color);
  border-radius: 100px;
}

@media(max-width: 850px) {
  .toggle_button {
    display: flex;
  }
  nav ul {
    height: min-content;
    width: 100%;
    background: var(--background-color);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: var(--navbar-height);
  }
  nav li {
    height: min-content;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul a {
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  .expandable_li {
    display: block;
  }
  .expandable_li label {
    padding: 30px 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
  .expandable_li:hover .dropdown {
    display: none;
  }
  .expandable_li input[type="checkbox"]:checked~.dropdown {
    display: block;
  }
  .dropdown {
    position: static;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .dropdown li {
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    position: static;
  }
  .dropdown li a {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  #toggle_button:checked~ul {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="logo" href="#">wesodev</a>
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle_button">
  <label for="toggle_button" class="toggle_button">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </label>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="expandable_li">
      <input type="checkbox" id="products_checkbox">
      <label for="products_checkbox">Products</label>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a href="#">Financist</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Coming Soon</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Firefox 105 (Ubuntu 22.04) doesn't seem to reproduce the problem; is it a specific browser you're having trouble with? If so, could you specify which?

Comment: On Chrome 106 (Win11), I don't see the behavior described by the OP.

Comment: Move your left and right border to the `li` instead of the `ul` and it will get rid of the black line - not sure what's causing it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Pete!
The solution to this problem is to move the border to the `.dropdown li` instead of `.dropdown`.